# Does fortran function pass by const reference?

Tags: fortran

I'm learning how to use functions in fortran and I came across several cases which made me believe that fortran function pass the argument by const reference. When I say "pass by const reference", I'm saying it in C++ sense. I searched online and didn't find related documents. The code which makes me believe fortran functions pass arguments by const reference is as follows.

```
  program try
  implicit none
  real sq
  real a,b
  write(*,*) sq(2)
  a=2
  write(*,*) sq(a)
  end program


  real function sq(x)
  real x
  sq=x**2
  return
  end
```

The output for this is

```
  0.0000000E+00
  4.000000
```

This result supports the idea that fortran functions pass arguments by reference, since `sq(2)` doesn't work. After this code, I put a new line `x=x+1` inside the definition of `sq`. The code looks like

```
  program try
  implicit none
  real sq
  real a,b
  write(*,*) sq(2)
  a=2
  write(*,*) sq(a)
  end program


  real function sq(x)
  real x
  x=x+1
  sq=x**2
  return
  end
```

This code does compile, but when I run it, it gives the following error

```
forrtl: severe (180): SIGBUS, bus error occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line           Source             
a.out              00000001000014DB  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              000000010000144C  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown

Stack trace terminated abnormally.
```

I guess I got this error because I can't modify the argument inside the function definition, which makes me believe that the argument is passed by const reference. The compiler I'm using is ifort 12.0.0. I'm running it on Mac OS X 10.6.8. Can anyone tell me whether my guess is true?

**Update**: According to the comment of @Jean, after modifying `sq(2)` to `sq(2.0)`. The first example will work, the second one still gives the same error. The modified version of the first example is

```
  program try
  implicit none
  real sq
  real a,b
  write(*,*) sq(2.0)
  a=2
  write(*,*) sq(a)
  end program


  real function sq(x)
  real x
  sq=x**2
  return
  end
```

The output is

```
4.000000
4.000000
```

I don't know why this simple modification will work. Hopefully someone can clarify for me.

Comment: In your examples, notice you are passing an integer to a function that expects a real. Try `sq(2.0)` instead. Arguments are passed by reference in Fortran, by default.

Comment: While not answering the question (I haven't the time and it's possibly a little too broad) I'll note that the second program isn't valid (even with the `2.0` mentioned above) because of the modification.

Comment: @francescalus True. I think some compilers may (wrongly) accept this, if the constant is stored in a data segment (or even on the stack as a local variable, by the caller, before pushing the reference for the callee). On Windows, gcc-4.9.2 crashes, but Absoft 4.0.4 does not.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut. Thanks for the comment. I changed 2 to 2.0. In the first example, `sq(2.0)` does return `4.0000`. But the second one still doesn't work.

Comment: You first shuld specify what you mean by const reference becausebthat is not a Fortran term. Do not think in C++ when programming in Fortran.

Comment: @VladimirF Yes, I mean pass by const reference in C++ sense. But I don't think pass by reference or pass by value is specific to C++. They are common concepts in programming.

Comment: The first example works because the program will pass a reference (a pointer if you prefer) to a constant, to sq. The second crashes (probably) because the constant is in a protected segment. And since the second case is not standard Fortran, it's a perfectly valid consequence that the program crashes. Unlike C, you have to be careful when you change parameters of a function: if you pass a constant, it's wrong. As a former C programmer, I was bitten by this many times... Fortran does not pass by value, by default.

Comment: In Fortran you just pass a variable and you can modify it under some conditions. Thats all. It often happens to be passes as an address, but you should learn the Fortran rules.

Comment: If you discover Fortran after some C or C++ habits, you should really have a look at the standard: [Fortran 2008](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf).

Comment: Learn to use explicit interfaces (preferably using modules!) and always specify `intent`. The compiler will find the errors you show.

Comment: @VladimirF I happen to understand the rules much better when I know what the compiler does under the hood ;-) Anyway, Fortran has also the VALUE attribute (see 12.4.1.2 of [Fortran 2003](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/04/04-007.pdf)). Good point about modules.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut But why simply change `sq(2)` to `sq(2.0)` will make the first one work? I think fortran will do automatic type conversion.

Comment: OK. BTW, `VALUE` arguments are also passed by address if not `bind(C)` so don't depend on the details too much.

Comment: There isn't automatic type conversion for arguments.  If you want to pass a real, you have to pass a real (even of the correct kind).  In this case a compiler may not, and in some cases can not, check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you should use explicit interfaces. Then the compiler is able to check argument types. There are different possibilities to do that. For larger programs use modules, for smaller ones, you can include your procedure in the main program by using the `contains` keyword.

Here is a slightly modified version of your code:

```
program try
    implicit none
    real a,b
    write(*,*) sq(2.0)
    a=2
    write(*,*) sq(a)

contains

real function sq(x)
    real, value :: x
    x=x+1
    sq=x**2
    return
end

end program
```

What's new?

1. the function is included in the main program with the `contains` keyword. When doing so, you don't have to declare sq like you did before in your third line. Also, the compiler can now check the argument type. Try to write `2` instead of `2.0` and see what happens.
2. You are right about the references. In Fortran arguments are passed by reference. If your argument is not a variable but just a number, then you can not change it within the procedure because it is constant. If you want variables to be passed by value, use the `value` keyword.